# PHP: Refresh page on invalid form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I refresh a page with a form on submission pending the outcome of the submitted data and display a result.

e.g I have a page with a form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit form "/>
</form>
```

The engine that handles the form is external, but required in the page:

```
require_once 'form_engine.php';
```

form_engine.php checks the input,

```
$success = "true";
$errorMessage = " ";
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ( $name == '') {
      $errorMessage = 'Please enter your name';
      $success = false;
}
else (if $success = true) {
   // do something with the data

}
```

The form page contains the result:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit form "/>
</form>
<p><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
```

Will the error message get displayed after the form is submitted incorrectly? Or do I have to use a session to store it?

Comment: Yes, use sessions. Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: As a sideline point your `form_engine.php` has a few syntax and logic errors. `else ( if` and `( $success = true )` and `$success = "true";`

Comment: These should be fixed to be `else if (` and `($success == true)` and `$success = true;`

Comment: if you submit the form on the same page, then there isn't any need for using sessions BUT in your case, you want to use form_engine.php as separate php form submission code handler, therefore, you have to use session to store the value of $errorMessage and then you can access it in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']))
```

instead of

```
if ( $name == 'name')
```

**UPDATE**

Try this, it should give you the idea:

```
<?php

    $errorMessage = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name']=='') {
            $errorMessage = 'Please enter your name';
        }
        else {
           // do something with the data
           echo "Success!!";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post">
   <input type="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<p><?php if ($errorMessage) echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
```

Note: leaving out the `action` attribute will just submit the form to the current page

Note 2: The PHP here could very well be stored in another page. Using `require()` is the same as putting the code directly into the page.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't the `value=""` force this to be set and just have an empty value? EDIT: Wait .. Html.. Yeah, I'm wrong.

Comment: that's not the point of the question. I'm wondering how to refresh the page, not check if name was posted.

Comment: @user3143218 when do you want the page to refresh?

Comment: when the user clicks submit. Sorry forgot to add the submit button on the example.

Comment: @user3143218 The page will automatically refresh when the user hits submit, to whichever url is in the `action`, which in your case is the current page. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: ok. But does it store the error message on the refresh after submitting?

Comment: Ahh ok ok I see, so I set the form action to the engine, rather than including the engine in the page;

Comment: No ... well maybe... but hang on I am working on an updated answer

Comment: @ChristopherWirt You were right - I did need to check if `$_POST['name'] == ''`

Answer (score 3):

You can use redirect on php side:

```
header('Location: www.mysite.com/index.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a little confused in terms of the exact process that occurs in terms of rendering a page, as do some of those commenting. You do not need to use sessions to solve this problem. There is no need to store anything server-side between page requests because the user's browser with retain everything that you need, at least for this situation. My guess is the others took you mentioning an "external engine" and thought that the form would be submitting away to a different site/page.

#### form loops

Below is a diagram showing a typical form request loop:

[image: a chart showing a typical flow of request and then render for a form]

You do not have to do this, as coding is as much about personal preference to anything else, but typically people will design their form to submit back to the same URI that generated it — as you seem to be doing in your example, by leaving the action attribute blank. By doing this, as long as you embed everything you wish to pass back to the server side within the form — each time the user submits — that information will be resent and be available in PHP.

Obviously you need to be wary of what information might constitute as sensitive, as this data should only ever be written into markup if your requests are protected by HTTPS/SSL. You should also filter/escape any user input to prevent markup injection into your site. You can prevent many problems by using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), however this can cause issues depending on the values you are trying to capture from the user. Because you are using double quoted HTML attributes (the right way to do them ;) I have not set the `ENT_QUOTES` option.

#### back to the point

So in the above loop the user will be shown the form for the first time, and after any subsequent submit, which means that each time your PHP notices that there is an error you can just add your message into the page flow. The trick with this kind of system is what exactly do you do once the form is fully complete. To get out of the loop most people will use a header location call:

```
<?php

require_once 'form_engine.php';

$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
$name = htmlentities($name);

if ( $success ) {
  header('location: next-step.php');
  exit;
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit form "/>
</form>
<?php

if ( $errorMessage ) {
  echo "<p>$errorMessage</p>";
}

?>
```

#### form engine repairs

You should also rectify your `form_engine.php` as per my comments above and Shekhar Joshi's answer, although I would keep the header code outside of your engine logic, and leave that decision to the code that requires in the engine — as the above does.

Comment: @user3143218 ~ No problem, now your next step is where/how do you store the submitted details :) If you are building a one off form, you can store direct to a database before you header off. If you are building a chain of forms (recommended rather than a long singular form.. in terms of UX), it might be best to look into sessions or build some functions to help you aggregate the user input and create a dynamic form that updates depending on what "step" the user is on i.e. rewrite the available inputs as the user progresses.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of creating a column like ("steps"), when each step is completed I can update the value (i.e - step1, step2, step3, completed). That way the user can leave and comeback and their progress is stored. I could then check if the value is completed that way as well.

Comment: I'd be careful with that route myself, it's not a bad idea, but it's best to design form steps around the stored user information -- and not based on their perceived location within a rigid page system. For example, imagine later on adding a new field to the step process. If you support people returning halfway through completion (you will need sessions/cookies/localStorage) you'd want those users taken back to where the now missing value is, so it can be filled in. If you're always calculating their "location" on each request (based on their missing answers), you get this behaviour for free.

Answer (score 1):

may be, you are looking for this! the header() method.

```
$success = true;
$errorMessage = " ";
$name = $_POST['name'];

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
 if ( $_POST['name'] == '') {
      $errorMessage = 'Please enter your name';
      $success = false;
      header('Location: www.something.com/some.php');
 }
 else if ($success == true) {
   // do something with the data
}

}
```